# angularjs + jsonp returns a fail

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a sample app that will grab data using JSONP to populate. I have it put up at http://angular.onagrag.com/  and clicking on register.

The file I am trying to load is at http://api.onagrag.com/data.json

When I access http://angular.onagrag.com/register it fires the error method of the object (and it fires it twice)

here is the angular js file that I am using (it is also located at http://angular.onagrag.com/js/test.js

It runs fine if I use local data (e.g. use the $http.get method instead of the $http.jsonp method), but will not work with jsonp. Any help is appreciated!

```
var App = angular.module('popdust', ['ngResource']).config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
  $location.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
}]);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routes) {

  $routes.when('/register',{
    templateUrl : '/templates/register.html',
    controller : RegisterCtrl
  });

  $routes.when('/',{
    templateUrl : '/templates/home.html',
    controller : HomeCtrl
  });  



}]);
var HomeCtrl = function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.title = 'We are home';
  $scope.obj = ['one', 'two','three'];
};

var RegisterCtrl = function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.title = 'Register!';
    $scope.handleData = function(data){
        $scope.fields = data;
    }
  $scope.fetchjsonp = function(){
    $http.jsonp('http://api.onagrag.com/data.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
            alert("success");        
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("YOU FAIL");
        });
  }

  $scope.fetch = function(){
    $http.get('js/data.json').success($scope.handleData);
  }

    $scope.fetchjsonp(); 
};

HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$location'];
RegisterCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$location'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like the problem is with your resource. When I check http://api.onagrag.com/data.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK I get the following response:

```js
[{
    "id" : "first_name",
    "title" : "First Name",
    "description" : "The name your parents gave you"
  },{
    "id" : "last_name",
    "title" : "Last Name",
    "description" : "In Spanish, it's called your apellido (or something like that)"
}]
```

This is not a valid [JSONP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). With the request parameter `callback=nameOfCallbackFn` the response should be a single function call to a function named nameOfCallbackFn (with the result as it's only parameter).

Update: The server that serves the JSONP must read the `callback` request parameter and respond with a file that does a method call to the request method name. When you use the angular `$http.jsonp` method, angular will change the callback request parameter to the correct angular jsonp callback method name (atm they seem to be named `angular.callback._0`, `..._1` etc). You can't serve a static file as this name might change from one request to the other. This was not clear in my original answer.

Something like this:

```js
nameOfCallbackFn ( [{
    "id" : "first_name",
    "title" : "First Name",
    "description" : "The name your parents gave you"
  },{
    "id" : "last_name",
    "title" : "Last Name",
    "description" : "In Spanish, it's called your apellido (or something like that)"
}] );
```

Where `nameOfCallbackFn` is specified by angular.

JSONP has some potential security vulnerabilities - you can read more about them and how to prevent them in your angular app [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Comment: I understand that and got it to work if I add a generic function to javascript JSON_CALLBACK(), but how do I bake the callback into the controller.. so that I have access the the $scope object?

Comment: You do that in the success function `.success(function(data){ $scope.data = data; ...`

Comment: I guess I just don't follow... do I include callback=JSON_CALLBACK to the URL in the jsonp method? if I don't I get an error ... also it ends up invoking the error method and never get success... can you take a second peek at my changes and let me know if I'm doing something glaringly wrong?

Comment: You have to change http://api.onagrag.com/data.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK - right now it responds with an array, but it should be a function call - similar to this: http://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero

Comment: It's invalid JSONP if I do it that way too, btw.

Comment: Ok, it seems to me like you're serving a static file. I think my original answer was a bit confusing, I've tried to clarify it.

Comment: I can't get success() to catch the response at all. I can however get it working just fine but setting JSON_CALLBACK in the global window scope. The documentation on the angular.js website does not indicate that success is applicable to jsonp requests.